# Flag Queue is showing a very old flagged answer

Tags: discussion, review, flags

As having 10K+ reputation I do flag review on regular basis on Stack Overflow. Today I saw an very old flag approx 7 months old, here is a snap shot,

> [image]

Just about half an hour it was not showing there and suddenly it started showing. It is a Not an Answer flag of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933379/996493).

Generally I notice that flag takes approx 24 hours to handle, then how come this very old flag is still in the queue ? About half an hour it was not there.

Comment: Maybe it's an audit? ;)

Comment: That answer is just as bad as the question to begin with...

Comment: @animuson Yes, but it looks like again the flag got declined 2nd time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The post was flagged on Oct 3, 2012, and that flag was declined. A second flag came in 39 minutes ago, which is why you see the ***x2*** (meaning, 'times two') next to the flag.

What this is telling you is:

- The aggregate count of flags on that post is two (declined, old, new, otherwise, all of them)
- The post was first flagged on Oct 3

... this isn't exactly intuitive, I know, but if you see something like this, it generally means that a flag that was once declined was subsequently raised again by another user, you just see the time stamp of the first flag.

As moderators can see *who flagged*, this is presented a little more sensibly, where the most recent flag is clearly differentiated. A bit confusing, but all you have to really worry about is if the flag has merit.