# Can we have flag queue in sorted manner or can we have "skip" button in flag queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

When we are viewing flag queue we are having list of flags in random order. Following is an example.

[image]

When we start looking flag lists we do following actions,

- flag the post,
- disagree the flag,
- skip the flag for which we are not sure

Once visiting full list if we visit the link again it loads the remaining flag posts in random order.
I believe the reason to keep it in random order should to re-check the previous flag again if we haven't look it properly.

Generally when we visit the link we wish the look for new flag posts first, So what my suggestion is can we have

- flag queue in ascending order for the time flag post ? or
- can we have option either to visit queue in random or in sorted format ?

**Updation** : As [nhahtdh] ([Can we have flag queue in sorted manner or can we have "skip" button in flag queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182600/can-we-have-flag-queue-in-sorted-manner#comment556431_182600)) mention in the comment that the above scenario may lead to any flag old flag to the bottom of the queue which remain un-actioned. So we can have another option as to add "Skip" button like below,

[image]

Its the same click on "Skip" button it will hide that flag post from the current user in case of user is not sure which action to take.

Comment: I think this is by-design, so that if multiple people are reviewing flags they won't all see the same posts.

Comment: @hammar of course it is by-design, that's why I am requesting for change.

Comment: `I believe the reason to keep it in random order should to re-check the previous flag again if we haven't look it properly.` I don't think a post that you have acted on will show up again in the next refresh. However, the random ordering makes sure that all the flags get an equal chance of being reviewed (although the reviewer may not take any action).

Comment: @nhahtdh not acted one, but the skipped one keep loading in queue again & again.

Comment: I think what you need might be a Skip button (which means "Please don't show this again, I don't want to review it", rather than "Skip it for now, show it later"). I don't think order everything by the timestamp is a good idea, since the timestamp is of the first flag on the post, [which might happen years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182036/flag-queue-is-showing-a-very-old-flagged-answer).

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, skip button is nice idea, btw link you provided is totally different case.

Comment: @Lucifer: Yes, it is different, but related. Since the timestamp is of the first flag, if there is a new flag years later, like in the link, then the flag is unlikely to be handled when people choose to view the list in order.

Comment: @nhahtdh oh yes, agree with you, in this case "skip" button is good option. Let me edit my question.

Comment: To be clear, you just want to be able to sort the random generated list by time / type?

Comment: @TimPost yes you are right.

Comment: Has anything been done about the skip button idea? Rejected? Will be done in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some form of sorting (by number of flags, but descending instead of ascending, I think) has been implemented since you requested this - but the person who did so forgot to update the sidebar text, which still says "This list is in random order."