# Review queue - filter by questions age/date?

Tags: discussion, review

Is it possible to filter the questions in the close review queue by the date the question appeared?

I want to concentrate on new questions, but there are a lot of old questions that have many votes, answers but now they are flagged as off-topic or duplicate.

Is it possible to configure filter, so that such old questions would not appear in my review queue?

Comment: Related [Can we have flag queue in sorted manner or can we have “skip” button in flag queue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182600/173001?)