# Can we display latest flag time in flag queue?

Tags: discussion, review, 10k-tools, flags

When any user flag a post for very first time that time is displayed in the flag queue. Now whenever the post gets flag for second time ( considering if the previous flag was declined and post is not deleted by OP or mod ) the flag queue always shows first flag's time in flag queue. Have a look at following image from my [older question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182036/173001).

> [image]

The same kind of case today again I saw in flag queue, see the image,

> [image]

I know that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but now a days SE is concentrating more on quality part as more and more users are joining. So I think now the logic to display flag time should be change to display latest flag time. What's your view on this ?